# How to add product in filter

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

I want to add product filter in account invoice model. How to do it?Any help appreciated.
Is it can be done by using related field?

[image]

Comment: I suggest create menuitem contains `account_invoice_line`, then you can filter by account_invoice and product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add new "field" filter in the search view:

```xml
<field name="invoice_line" string="Product" 
    filter_domain="[('invoice_line.product_id', 'ilike', self)]" />
```

For newer Odoo Versions (field name changed):

```xml
<field name="invoice_line_ids" string="Product" 
    filter_domain="[('invoice_line_ids.product_id', 'ilike', self)]" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a computed fields on account.invoice and add a search funtion on it.